Eskimo Boy in Kayak on Long Journey
I know this is a longshot, but I'm trying to find the title of a movie from the 1970s.  It was about an eskimo boy and was, in part, a coming of age movie.  I don't remember the reasoning, but the boy had to, for some reason, make a journey through the wilderness and I think most of it was with him in his canoe or kayak.  (I think it was to save his Father or someone and he was going for help, but I can't be sure.)
I do remember the native legend of the Kushtaka played a significant part.  He was scared of it coming for him and I remember one scene where he had fallen asleep in his canoe and woke up, scared it might come for him (or scared that he might have seen it).  (I've also seen various other spellings of Kushtaka, such as Kooshdaka.)
This wasn't a high budget undertaking and was like a number of movies I remember seeing in that time period that were aimed at kids or intended as family movies.

Sounds like Joniko and the Kush Ta Ka (AKA Wilderness Journey, Alaska Boy and Frontier Alaska) from 1969. From the NY Times:

In this children's adventure, a young Alaskan boy must confront the "Kush Ta Ka" (the Tlingit "spirit of fear") in order to save the life of an injured geologist who broke his leg while the boy was leading him on a wilderness expedition. The boy leaves the geologist and sets off alone in his kayak to find his father, who has taken off to the seal grounds in the north. As he travels, the boy sees great grizzlies and giant sperm whales, but when he paddles into an ice-filled sea, he begins to fear the evil spirits that live there. He struggles to overcome the power of Kush Ta Ka so he can complete his heroic mission.



I wish I could find more detail to connect this with the few memories I have of the movie, but this is a big help, especially for convincing me I wasn't making this up.  I was sure the title was "Wilderness Journey," but that kept bringing up a movie from the 1990s.  It's nice to know I did remember that correctly and the different spelling explains why I couldn't find it using "Kushtaka" as a search term.  I'm curious about how you found it.  Did you remember the title "Joniko and the Kush Ta Ka?"  Also, since it's so low rated, I can understand why there's so little information available!

Glad you found it. Google was just kinder to me, I guess. I doubt I've ever seen this movie, and it does seem pretty obscure (I couldn't even find any clips).

I have found, in the past, that my friends and I, in different parts of the country and the world actually got different results from Google when we used the same search terms in the same order.  I don't know if that still happens, though.
